# Viewpager fragments not overlapping activity elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a activity where i have some images,textview,a button and viewpager. Viewpager has height and width to match parent and all the layouts have background as white color . Now when the activity loads viewpager gets its fragments by adapter and it loads fragments. Now the images,textview are hidden behind the loaded fragments but the button does not gets hidden and its shown in fragments. Why is this happening ?

THis is my layout of activity with viewpager as last element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.appointmentno.android.LogoFrontScreen"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/rel_center_logo">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_height"
        android:src="@drawable/finalc"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/img_logo_c"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/logo_name"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_logo_c"
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        style="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/logo_text_size"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/logo_underline"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/app_name_underline"
        style="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt_progress_report"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_center_logo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxLines="10"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_2"
    android:id="@+id/btn_enter_app"
    android:layout_below="@id/rel_center_logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:id="@+id/logo_screen_progress"
    android:layout_below="@id/rel_center_logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/txt_ver_alert"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.appointmentno.android.LogoFrontScreen"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/rel_center_logo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_height"
    android:src="@drawable/finalc"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/img_logo_c"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/logo_name"
    android:id="@+id/app_name"
    style="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logo_text_size"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/logo_underline"
    android:id="@+id/app_name_underline"
    style="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/rel_center_logo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/rel_center_logo">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/txt_progress_report"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:maxLines="10"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/str_2"
android:id="@+id/btn_enter_app"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="84dp"/>

<ProgressBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminate="true"
android:id="@+id/logo_screen_progress"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:id="@+id/txt_ver_alert"
android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager_gallery"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I basically divided your views into to groups (according to what I believe you want) and put them into their respective LinearLayouts. So in the end you have one RelativeLayout that holds two LinearLayouts and a ViewPager.

Comment: @shreyansjain I'm not completely sure why the button was showing, but I noticed you had a few views with the `layout_below="someID"`, so to clean things up I simply put them into a `LinearLayout` as that is what they are meant for: To align views in a single direction with no overlapping. So there is no point in using a `RelativeLayout`. Only your main `RelativeLayout` that holds everything is necessary in order to attain your desired layout. 
If it worked for you, please mark this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: ok i have not tested it yet, if it runs i will mark as correct.

Comment: @shreyansjain I see. Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll have another look at it.